# Mvc web api changes the JSON datetime due to UTC

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have date in javascript in the format Tue Sep 30 00:00:00 UTC+0200 2014
I send it with http post.
On the controller in MVC Web Api I get 
29/09/2014 22:00:00.

What is going on and how can I solve it?

Comment: I will answer me question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realize that the JSON formater of WebApi convert the date into UTC. therefor what I should do is return the date into local time of the server: TimeZone.CurrentTimeZon.ToLocalTime(dt).
Confusing and it was hard to find the answer.